# Python pip install altered data files

Tags: python, pip, pickle, setup.py, distutils

I have a python package that contains some data in a subdirectory of the package in numpys npz format. So the directory looks like

```
- setup.py
- Main Package

- -  Data Directory
- - -  file1.npz
- - -  file2.npz
- - -  filen.npz

- -  Module 1
- -  Module 2
- -  Module n 
- -  init.py
```

When I run the code without running pip install (or setup.py install), the package data (in Data Directory) is imported just fine using np.load(). But, when I run pip install . (or setup.py install) then import the package, np.load spits out

```
ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False
```

and when putting allow_pickle=True

```
OSError: Failed to interpret file <filename> as a pickle
```

To check if the two files were the same (the uninstalled data file and the installed data file, which should be the same), I ran sha256sum and got two very different hashes between the local version of the data file and the pip installed version. So something is happening to my data file as pip (or distutils) is installing it. For reference, my setup.py file looks like

```
setup(
    name="main_package",
    version="0.1",
    description="(...)",
    author="(...)",
    packages=["main_package",
                "main_package.module1",
                "main_package.module2",
                "main_package.module3",
                "main_package.module4",
                "main_package.module5",
                "main_package.Data Directory"
                ],
    package_data={"main_package": ['Data Directory/*.npz']},
    ext_modules=extensions,

)
```

with some unimportant extensions and functions defined earlier which dont mess with the data directory.

**My question is then**: what is pip and distutils doing to my data file and why cant numpy load the installed version but can load the local version

For reference, Im running fedora36

Comment: Have you built sdist and/or wheel of this project? Have you checked those `.npz` files in the sdist and wheel?

Comment: If i create a source distribution and check the file using sha256sum, the hash is the same as the local version (the expected hash). But if I create a wheel and check the file (prior to installation, I just extract the wheels contents), its the same hash as the one after pip installing the package, so the incorrect one

Comment: OK, interesting... I do not know if it is meaningful or a false lead. Maybe someone else will chime in.